# systemLayoutSizeFitting returns zero always

Tags: ios, autolayout

Based on Apple's [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622624-systemlayoutsizefittingsize?language=objc), `systemLayoutSizeFitting` is supposed to respect current constraints on the `UIView` element when returning the optimal size. However, whenever I run following code, I would get `{0, 0}` for `UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize` and `{1000, 1000}` for `UIView.layoutFittingExpandedSizeSize` input.

```
let mainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 375, height: 50)))
mainView.backgroundColor = .red
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = mainView

let subview = UIView()
subview.backgroundColor = .yellow
mainView.addSubview(subview)
subview.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.width.equalToSuperview().dividedBy(3.0)
    make.left.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
}
mainView.setNeedsLayout()
mainView.layoutIfNeeded()

subview.frame

subview.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
```

I noticed that if I change the `width` constraint to something constants, then I'd get a valid value from `systemLayoutSizeFitting`. Trying to understand why such behavior is happening and if it's possible to get a right value from `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(_ size: CGSize)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation seems rather lacking on this one.

It appears that `.systemLayoutSizeFitting` is highly dependent on the `.intrinsicContentSize` of the element. In the case of a `UIView`, it has no intrinsic content size (unless you've overridden it).

So, if the related constraint is a *percentage* of another constraint, `.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)` will return `{0, 0}`. I gather this is because the related constraint could change (to Zero), therefor the minimum value is, in fact, Zero.

If you change your `.width` constraint to a constant (such as `mainView.frame.width * 0.3333`) then you'll get a valid size value, as the constant width constraint becomes the intrinsic width.

If your subview is a `UILabel`, for example, that element *will* have an intrinsic size, and `.systemLayoutSizeFitting` should return a size value that you'd expect.

Here's an example using a `UILabel` that will demonstrate:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let mainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 375, height: 50)))
mainView.backgroundColor = .red
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = mainView

let v = UILabel()
v.text = "Testing"
v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
v.backgroundColor = .green
mainView.addSubview(v)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 3.0 / 10.0),
    v.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.leftAnchor),
    v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.topAnchor),
    v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.bottomAnchor),
    ])

mainView.setNeedsLayout()
mainView.layoutIfNeeded()

v.frame

v.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
```

Comment: That totally makes sense and aligned with what I have experiences also. Thanks for explaining it in details.