# How do I get the height of a UIView that dynamically changes based on label content - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a UIView that changes height based on the contents of the labels inside it. I need to use the height of the view to set the `preferredContentSize()`, but when I use the  `myView.frame.size.height` or `myView.bounds.height` it gets the original height, and not the new height with the updated labels. At fist in `viewDidLoad()` I got the height before I set the labels, so I thought that was the problem, but even after I moved it, it still wasn't getting the updated height. Any ideas on how to get the height after the labels have been updated?

Answer (score 0):

UILabels will have an intrinsicContentSize so if you're using auto layout to layout your UILabel within your view, you should be able to use `myView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)` to get the optimal size of the view.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622624-systemlayoutsizefitting

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55482896/6416739 for an example using `systemLayoutSizeFitting` with UILabel